# I'd like to make a line of code which prints a vlookup formula to the cells going down a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is the formula I'd like to print to each cell going down the column:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(E2,C2), WORKABILITY_INDEX!$A$1:$B$82, 2, FALSE)
```

I am using a statement like the one below:

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) <> "" Then
                 Cells(i, "L").Formula = "=VLookup(Concatenate(RC[-8],RC[-10]), ""WORKABILITY_INDEX!$A$1:$B$82"", 2, False)"
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: And is it working? If not, how is it failing? What do your data look like?

Comment: I get a runtime error, so nothing is printing out in the column cells.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post, I'm sorry for not knowing the html off the top of my head.

Comment: "WORKABILITY_INDEX!$A$1:$B$82" is a separate worksheet within the same workbook with data going down column1 and column2.  The reason for concatenation is to make a unique identifier, so it appears to be gibberish, but each value is unique.

Comment: Ok so I delimited the formula's table-array argument with double quotes and I no longer get a runtime error.  However, I get #VALUE! error in the cells containing the formula.  I'll update the code in the depiction at the top of the page with the double-quotes.

Comment: with double double-quotes removed I get Runtime Error '1004: Application defined or object defined error'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of things wrong with your code -- first, the value of `Last` was always 1, not the number of the last row.

Try this:

```
Sub insertFormulas()
Last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) <> "" Then
            Cells(i, "L").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(E" & i & ",C" & i & "), WORKABILITY_INDEX!$A$1:$B$82, 2, FALSE)"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Key changes:
1. I used the `UsedRange` property of the active sheet to get the number of rows.
2. I scrapped the R1C1 formula style and used your desired formula output instead. The relative cell references are built by concatenating the row number into the formula string.

Comment: Wow, this totally worked.  I like how you used variable 'i' for the arguments in the concatenation func.  Thank you for this creative solution.  I am indebted to you :)

Comment: Like how you can concatenate pieces of the string together to compose the entire value in the cell.  I'll definitely be using this method a lot in the future.  Again, thanks so much!